# Can connecting a router to another router impair connection to local clients in the network?

Tags: networking

The building  of the school I am in is covered with metal plates, blocking cell reception inside, and there was no Wi-Fi, so I brought my own Wi-Fi router and plugged it in an unused ethernet port. It seemed to work fine, I could connect to the Internet with no problems via the Wi-Fi.

But after a few days, the school's IT administration removed my router because they said it was causing problems for the other computers in the network. These computers need to connect to a local server (Windows logon stuff), and they said that because there were 2 routers on the network (their wired network host and my own router being connected to it), the computers randomly sent their requests to the network host router (where the server was) or to my router (where the server wasn't), thus causing random logon fails. I apologized.

But now that I thought about it, it just doesn't seem to make sense. Why would the request be erroneously sent to my router? And even if it was, shouldn't that router just route the request to the server because it's apparently on the same network?

So, is it really possible that connections to local network clients can be impaired by a second router being plugged into the main one?

---

*Thanks for reading all the way through :)*

Answer (score 3):

More than likely your router has [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) enabled.  Two DHCP servers on the same network can definitely cause issues.  Machines looking to get dynamic addresses can be put in the wrong address space.  This would cause all sorts of headaches.

Comment: To add a little detail: Computers on the network, when first connecting (and periodically after) send a broadcast out to all computers requesting an IP address. A DHCP server listens for these requests, and will send back a response telling it how to configure itself to speak properly on the network. Most home routers have a built-in DHCP server which is enabled by default (you can disable it). Your router likely responded to some of these requests, giving incorrect configuration information in response, leaving them unable to communicate.

Comment: Adding a router to a network you don't control is asking for trouble.  You don't know their configuration and could introduce all kinds of problems/security risks/etc.

Comment: Would disabling DHCP on my router fix everything?

Comment: Assuming that was the problem, then it should.  Without DHCP it would just become a switch and wireless AP.